# How can I make the Play action not redirect me to another page

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I am using Play 2.3.1 with Java

I have a form that uses an action and should return Result ok().
My problem is that when it does return ok() it sends me to the URL mapped on the routes file, even though it should remain on the same page.

How can I fix this/What am I doing wrong?

my code:

The action

```
  public static Result postComment(){
    CommentModel comment = Form.form(CommentModel.class).bindFromRequest().get();
    comment.author = loggedUser;

    if(!comment.content.isEmpty()){
        return ok();
    }
    return null;

}
```

The route

```
POST    /postComment                controllers.Application.postComment()
```

The form

```
<form action="@routes.Application.postComment()" method="post">
    <label for="comment" class=required>Your comment</label>
     <textarea rows="2" name="content"></textarea>
     <br/>
     <button class="btn btn-primary">Comment</button>
</form>
```

Also, how can I make it so that when the action doesn't go into the 'if' nothing happens, since it always says that I need to return a Result? Is there a Result return that does nothing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"I have a form that uses an action and should return Result ok(). My problem is that when it does return ok() it sends me to the URL mapped on the routes file, even though it should remain on the same page."*

I can't see anything wrong here. If you just return an OK / HTTP status code 200 your client/browser will get exactly just that. Play's routing happens before the action is called. Maybe you do something in your JavaScipt that gets activated after your form was submitted successfully?

*"Also, how can I make it so that when the action doesn't go into the 'if' nothing happens, since it always says that I need to return a Result? Is there a Result return that does nothing ?"*

You have to return a Result. But If you just want to tell your client side about a failed POST you can consider one of the 400er status code, e.g. 400 / Bad Request. In Play its `return badRequest()`.

Comment: When it gets to "return ok()" it redirects me to "localhost:9000/postComment" (the path defined on the routes file). I don't want that. I want to stay on the same page I made the comment. I don't have JavaScripts for that form. Maybe is something from inside Play?

Comment: I'm confused. Play's routing sends you to your action `postComment()`. In this method you do a `return ok()` and Play sends a HTTP response to your client with the status code OK/200. The `return ok()` does no redirecting.

Comment: I understand this is not normal behavior but is what is happening. I am at "localhost:9000/user/3" where I have the form to post a comment, I click on the button and at the same time the form is posted I am thrown to "localhost:9000/postComment", that is not supposed to be a view. This is not standard behavior, right?

Comment: This exactly what should happen. It's standard behaviour. Form in browser -> Play's routing -> Controller's postComment() -> OK

Comment: Ok. So there is no way for me to remain on the user page after pressing the form button, correct?

Comment: You can always do an ajax post request. With an ajax request your browser don't change the page (unless you tell it explicitly to do so).